# How can you tell which tnsnames.ora file is used by a .net call?

Tags: .net, oracle

I have multiple versions of Oracle and it saved tnsnames.ora files all over the place.  Older ones got stored in program files under oracle but newer ones got stored under an app directory in my hard drive.

I'm using the .net libraries provided by Oracle to connect with a .net app and it's telling me it cannot find the name I want to connect to.

I've updated all the tnsnames.ora files I could find.  Is there a way to tell what tnsnames.ora my app is trying to use to connect to Oracle with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Coming late to the party, but I've used [Sysinternals'](http://sysinternals.com) procmon.exe for doing something like this. Here are my notes to myself:

1. Start procmon.exe
2. **File > Capture Events** to turn off capturing
3. Press the **Show File System Activity** button (the rest on the right should be unset)
4. **File > Capture Events** to start capturing
5. Perform the activity that you want monitored
6. **File > Capture Events** to stop capturing
7. **Tools > File Summary** to find tnsnames.ora in the filename list

Answer (score 3):

The following links might provide some information:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_windows_tnsnames.ora_file_location.htm

http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=2554

For your development environment you might try putting the tnsnames.ora in the directory where your program executables are generated for now while you figure out which one is being used. The first tnsnames.ora that is used is the one in the current directory where the application is run from.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it seems that putting the tnsnames.ora in the same directly is very widely known.  I've [blogged about this](http://www.matthewedmondson.info/2012/10/using-tnsnamesora-with-your-net.html) and cited your answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: @m.edmondson Very interesting blog post and I especially liked the analogy to DNS. Also, I appreciate the citation, Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad you found it interesting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the environment variable TNS_ADMIN to consolidate all connections to one place. It is very helpful especially in the multiple home environments.

Set TNS_ADMIN variable to the path where tnsnames.ora file is. Note that this file can be stored anywhere, but typically under one of the ORACLE_HOME\network\admin.

IC

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem. This is the comment that I put into my program:
'Note: Program built with Ora 11 OracleDataAdaptor. For this to find 'db name', the 
 ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1 registry entry must have a value for TNS_ADMIN pointing to
 the correct directory for TNSNAMES.ORA.

Comment: Perhaps I am being obtuse but, _how_ does this answer the question?

Comment: This type of feedback must be posted as a comment and not as an answer of the question.