# ORA-12154 -- working in SQL PLUS not in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a working C# application running on my computer.  I have given it to a colleague and he gets the dreaded ORA-12154 ERROR.  After much searching and trying, we are at a loss at what to try next.

Setup:
C# makes a connection like

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
```

The ConnectionString has a value of `"Data Source=MY_TNS_ENTRY;USER ID=usernm;Password=passwd"`

The application includes the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll file.

Both machines have the Oracle 64Bit client installed (11g 11.2.0).  Both TNSNAMES files are identical.

On my colleague's computer he can run `sqlplus usernm/passwd@MY_TNS_ENTRY` at the command line and connect to the database.  When the C# app runs it throws the ORA-12154 ERROR.

What else should we be checking to find the cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that it is using a different TNS names file and that in that one the `MY_TNS_ENTRY` does not exist. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073219/how-can-you-tell-which-tnsnames-ora-file-is-used-by-a-net-call) question to see how to check which file it is using.

Answer (score 1):

ODP.NET Managed Driver uses a different search path for `tnsnames.ora` (and `sqlnet.ora`, et. al.) than SQL*Plus does. Almost every driver/application behaves differently in finding those files.

ODP.NET Managed Driver uses this path:

1. data source alias in the `dataSources` section under `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` section in the .NET config file.
2. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file at the location specified by `TNS_ADMIN` in the .NET config file. Locations can consist of either absolute or relative directory paths.
3. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present in the same directory as the `.exe`.

See [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8161)

Mayor difference to other application is ODP.NET Managed Driver does not read the Registry settings nor environment variable to determine value of `TNS_ADMIN`.